# Cannot update Android

Tags: updates, 5.1-lollipop

I have a ZTE Citrine LTE II from TracFone. I'm running Android 5.1.1. I can't seem to update Android to the latest version. Clicking "Software Update" near the bottom doesn't work ([images are too large](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B671h9AqqI7ZV1ZwX2NudjBaOUE?usp=sharing))

Following some guides tells me to click on "About Phone" and then look for a software thingamajig at the top...

[image: screenshot]

Is there any way to update a non-rootable TracFone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most Android phones it is down to the manufacturer to push updates to the phones.

I had a quick Google and it seems your phone's latest Android release is 5.1.1. Unless your manufacturer pushes another update you're pretty much stuck with that version I'm afraid.